# Netbeans 8 and xdebug very very slow

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, moodle

I've read other posts about this issue, but I can't get a satisfactory performance with xdebug 2.2.5 and netbeans 8.0.1 on a local web server (apache 2.4.9, php 5.5.12 on windows 7). Some pages load in over 40 seconds, worse than the remote server performances.
This is the xdebug section on my php.ini after the recommandations taken from some other post:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="xdebug-netbeans"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
```

P.S. I'm developing on moodle 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the theme designer mode is off in `/config.php`, debug is very slow when its on

```
$CFG->themedesignermode = false; // Debug is very slow when set to true.
```

Other than that these are the only differences I can see in my settings in `php.ini`

```
; Needs to be off for Netbeans xdebug - not sure why but its in my settings.
output_buffering = off ; Was 4096
; This setting is on by default - turned off here because it can interfere with xdebug
report_zend_debug = 0
; Settings from http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug
; zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20100525/xdebug.so
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so ; PHP 5.5.3
```

Comment: it's still slow, but now a little less