# XDEBUG with Netbeans 8.0.2 running rather slow

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I use Netbeans 8.0.2 with XDEBUG latest version for PHP7.0 having the following Setup:

```
zend_extension = "\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-7.0-vc14.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable            =on
xdebug.remote_handler           =dbgp
xdebug.remote_host          =127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port          =9000
xdebug.idekey               ="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_mode              =req
xdebug.var_display_max_children     =-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data     =-1
xdebug.var_display_max_depth        =-1
xdebug.max_nesting_level        =1023
xdebug.profiler_enable          =0
xdebug.show_local_vars          =0
```

Internally in Netbeans I tried a lot of Settings but it got not better.
The current setting within Netbeans is:

```
Max Data length:  1028               (tried up to 8192)
Depth of Strucures:   5              (tried 1 to 5)
Maximum Children:     256            (tried 1 to 256)
```

Debugging projects it takes 20, 30 seconds - sometimes longer or ending up with an exception - to do single steps f. e. on (easy) lines like this:

```
if($highest > $ship_val)
```

or

```
$t_attribute_option_data_array['SUPPRESS'] = 'true';
```

I'm getting nuts with this performance doing debugging.

Does anybody have an hint for me how to resolve this Issue with XDEBUG and Netbeans?

Thanks in advance!
Holger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 8 and xdebug very very slow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094069/netbeans-8-and-xdebug-very-very-slow)